# Creating CMakeLists for a project that depends on LLVM

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm

I've decided to try LLVM and the CMake build system for my language project, but I'm not sure how to generate a proper cross-platform CMakeLists for it. Running "llvm-config --libs" returns about a hundred libraries (I'm still not sure which of them I actually need) and "--cxxflags" gives me g++-specific flags (I wouldn't know how they translate to other compilers).

Is there a way to get output for different compilers from llvm-config? (Perhaps it depends on how llvm is compiled?)
If so, could I run llvm-config from CMakeLists and use its output instead of hard-coding it?
Otherwise, what are some maintainable alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

`llvm-config --cxxflags` will use the compiler you build LLVM with in the first place. So if you plan on using that and build LLVM itself with a different compiler than g++ (default), then you need to build LLVM itself with a different compiler - or not use `llvm-config` in the first place.

I went the former route, so I create a `build.sh`, which contains this:

```
CC=clang CXX=clang++ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=1  -DLLVM_T
ARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 ../llvm
make
```

I then have a makefile that uses `llvm-config` to define flags and such (I don't use `CMake`, but the concept should be possible to move to `CMake` quite easily). See: https://github.com/Leporacanthicus/lacsap/blob/master/Makefile